# How to find empty repos (zero commit) in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm using GitLab 11.9 (it's old, I know ....), and I need to list all the repositories that have been created but that are empty o with zero commits.

Is it possible to list them from admin interface o via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this with Gitlab API we will combine Projects API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

And the Commits API
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

To the following bash script (Make sure you have `curl` and `jq` installed)

```
#!/bin/bash

ACCESS_TOKEN=$1
GITLAB_URL=$2

curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" $GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/?per_page=50000 | jq '.[] | "\(.id) \(.web_url) \(.name)"' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/'| while read line
do
        PROJECT_ID=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1 )
        PROJECT_NAME=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f3- )
        REPO_URL=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2 )

        COMMIT_IDS=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" $GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/repository/commits | jq '.[].id')

        if [[ $COMMIT_IDS == "" ]]; then echo "$PROJECT_ID $PROJECT_NAME $REPO_URL";fi

done
```

Execution Example:

```
./my_script.sh "<your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com"
```

The output of this script will be the `Project ID` `Project Name` and `Project URL` of the repos with `0 commits`

E.G.

```
33294654 project-for-issues-286e58fd4f6a5603 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-qa-sandbox-group/qa-test-2022-01-31-18-09-07-311cfe607ff3ce9b/project-for-issues-286e58fd4f6a5603

33294612 project-with-ci-variables-c1b233588d3fbce7 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-qa-sandbox-group/qa-test-2022-01-31-18-09-05-68cad66167d10aa2/project-with-ci-variables-c1b233588d3fbce7
```

`Note`: This script assumes that you have less than 50.000 repositories in your Gitlab